# SQL filter out string that matches condition and with specific exception to pass

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

Sample data

```
| data_col            | 
| --------------------| 
| Realdata            |
| Firsttest           | 
| testSecond          | 
| onetesttwo          | 
| exceptiontestunique | 
| legitdata           |
```

I wanted to filter out all the data that contains test with the exception of one

My expected return result is:

```
Realdata
exceptiontestunique
legitdata
```

I can code this in PHP like this.

```
if (strpos($data, 'test') === false || $data === 'exceptiontestunique') return $data;
```

Or in JavaScript like this

```
if (data.indexOf('test') === -1 || data === 'exceptiontestunique') {
  return data;
}
```

But I need it in SQL

```
WHERE data_col NOT LIKE '%test%'
???????
```

```js
const datas = ['realdata', 'Firsttest', 'testSecond', 'onetesttwo', 'exceptiontestunique', 'legitdata'];

const filtered = datas.filter(data => {
  if (data.indexOf('test') === -1 || data === 'exceptiontestunique') {
    return data;
  }
})

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be not like, as long as the expected return result is good

Comment: What is the condition? Fetch if `test` is part of the beginning or part of the end of a word? And if `test` is somewhere in the middle, don't return that value?

Comment: @FaNo_FN I've updated the question and added a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that in your PHP/Js code you're defining two condition; any value that have 'test' in them but not `exceptiontestunique`. With a specific condition like that, you can achieve with `OR`. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE (data_col NOT LIKE '%test%' 
            OR data_col='exceptiontestunique');
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=35ec74cdb784bd1adca173e1eea9657e)

Comment: thank you very much. perfect!! I got confused with the NOT LIKE combination with OR

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM T
WHERE data_col NOT LIKE '%test%'
UNION ALL
(SELECT t.*
 FROM T
 WHERE data_col LIKE '%test%'
 LIMIT 1
);
```

Usually, `LIMIT` is used with `ORDER BY`, but you don't seem to care *which* "test" you get.

Comment: Hi, i updated the question to make it more clear, with samples in PHP and Javascript, I've also added a code snippet to run, hopefully that helps thank you